# Want to Generate this type of Graph in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, flutter-dependencies, stacked-bar-chart

I want to generate one this kind of graph in Flutter, I have provide the graph video link. If you know please provide me the solution, Please watch the video also and I have provided the datapoints also.

[image]

[History Graph Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gx9aSOivB8gfoiYcAlQf2V2l8Al6SLW8/view?usp=share_link)

[History Graph DataPoints](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1thSpkCk-0IhpWaVVNON0rD9liPdm6EN5hVHCdqwya8M/edit?usp=sharing)

I have tried Syncfusion Charts and Google Charts too but not able to do this type of graph. The graph which is generated in video is D3 Stacked bar Graph.

Comment: refer [syncfusion_flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts), and also refer [https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/chart-types/step-area](step_area) graph

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I have tried Syncfusion Charts but didn't find any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bar chart. Use `BarChartGroupData` for every minute or any interval you want with fl_chart [bar graph](https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/blob/main/repo_files/documentations/bar_chart.md). You need to calculate every each fill (the green part on your image) time in Y-axis `toY` and time Y-axis `fromY` parameters so it can hover. You also need to remove the space between bars with `groupsSpace` so it can look seamless.

I have not worked with not connected rod items but you can give this a try.

Comment: Already tried this but not working for me brother